# prevent code from compiling if an external project fails to build and install correctly

Tags: build, cmake

Is there a way to tell the CMake system that I don't want further compilation until the dependencies (external projects) are built and installed correctly?

Say a project depends on other libraries, which may or may not be present in the system. In case they're not, I use the `ExternalProject_Add` to download and install it. Yet, even though the configure part goes fine, building the external project doesn't happen until you type `make`. Now it doesn't make sense to compile the code if building the dependencies failed. I found in [CMake ExternalProject_Add() and FindPackage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446981/cmake-externalproject-add-and-findpackage) that maybe adding some dependencies would help, but that answer defines the dependency at configuration time, so it's not relevant to my situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you need to run superbuild to install dependencies, so simply if superbuild failed - you're not building your project. Can you explain how exactly you're using `ExternalProject_Add`? may be with little example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExternalProject_Add` will generate a custom target for building the dependency. If you don't want a target to be built in case building the dependency failed, [add a dependency](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) from that target to the external project's target.

```
ExternalProject_Add(my_external_lib [...])
add_executable(my_program [...])
add_dependencies(my_program my_external_lib)
```