# Rescanning CMake and passing parameters

Tags: cmake, dependency-management

I'm making a CMAKE file with an external project.  I'm following the example here: 
[CMake ExternalProject_Add() and FindPackage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446981/cmake-externalproject-add-and-findpackage)

However, I have a problem.  When I call cmake, I use `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`.  Unfortunately the -G parameter doesn't seem to be passed into the rescan target.  How can I relay applicable Cmake commands to any rescan?

I think this is the line I need to change

```
 add_custom_target(Rescan ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} DEPENDS Eigen3)
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package( Dep1 )

include (ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add (
                   Dep1
                   SVN_REPOSITORY https://svn.company.nl/svn/Dep1-trunk
                   SVN_REVISION -rHEAD
                   TIMEOUT 10
)

if (NOT Dep1_FOUND )
  add_custom_target(Rescan ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} DEPENDS Dep1)
else (NOT Dep1_FOUND)
  add_custom_target(Rescan)
endif (NOT Dep1_FOUND)

#build app
add_executable( Testapp main.cpp )
add_dependencies( Testapp Rescan )

if (${Dep1_FOUND})
  target_include_directories( Testapp PUBLIC ${Dep1_INCLUDE_DIR} )
  target_link_libraries( Testapp ${Dep1_LIBRARY} )
endif (${Dep1_FOUND})

#Install package
install(TARGETS Testapp EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just call

```
add_custom_target(Rescan ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G ${CMAKE_GENERATOR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} DEPENDS Eigen3)
```

See documentation for [CMAKE_GENERATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html) variable.

Comment: This helps thanks. However if someone uses -T or -A would I need to handle each case or is there something that will let me pass everything into cmake?

Comment: The respective variables are `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET` and `CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM`.

Comment: This answer helps with the -T and -A cases, but what about cases I haven't considered yet?  For example, what if someone passes a custom `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?  I'm sure I am missing a lot of possibilities.  Is there a generic way to pass everything?

Comment: @Stewart Generally, CMake picks up all cache variables from CMakeCache.txt during reconfiguring. But you seem to have another issue. You want to pass all CMake variables from your build directory into another separate build dir, am I right?

Comment: Since I need to build with `-G "MinGW Makefiles"`, I'm sure other people have other quirks, or preferences.  It would be fantastic if CMake picks up all cache variables, but I noticed that without adding `-G ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}` to my `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`, my build failed.  My problem is solved (hence the solved status), however in the interest of preventing other problems in the future, I'm probing about how to fix this in the  most generic way possible.