# How do i use add_subdirectory() after ExternalProject_Add() has finished downloading?

Tags: cmake, googletest, external-project

I basically ask the same question as has been ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805657/how-to-add-subdirectory-after-a-externalproject-add#43848284). The question has however not been answered.

I want to use googletest in my project. For this I'm using ExternalProject_Add() which clones the testsuite with git. After that, I like to use `add_subdirectory()`.

This is also what is described in the [official repository](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project). The nice thing about this approach is, that the build scripts in googletest handle the building process themself.

The problem is however, that `add_subdirectory()` can not find the source folder, since it does not exists from the start. Therefore, `add_subdirectory()` should depend on the completion of `ExternalProject_Add()`.

Is is possible to make `add_subdirectory()` dependent of `ExternalProject_Add()`, like add_dependencies() does for targets?

PS. I can make it all compile if I comment `add_subdirectory()` out, build it (which ends with an error because the googletest library is missing), uncomment it and build it again (success).

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    GIT_TAG         master
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND     ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    TEST_COMMAND      ""
    )

ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest source_dir binary_dir)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ${source_dir}/googletest/include)
set(GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIR ${source_dir}/googlemock/include)


add_subdirectory(${source_dir}
                 ${binary_dir})
```

Comment: Projects added using `ExternalProject_Add()` are only downloaded at build time, IIRC.

Comment: [Here is](https://github.com/Gluttton/munkres-cpp/blob/devel/tests/CMakeLists.txt) complete work example with dependencies.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable making this an answer until I've tried it, but [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) seems to be the CMake command you really want.  It is new in 3.11.

Comment: @John, I think this is exactly the answer that deserves to be accepted.

Comment: @John, I wonder if you could provide this as an answer, took me a while to find this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @dani and @Bikineev, I expanded my original answer to include more discussion and `FetchContent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [this tutorial](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/) to accomplish that.  Just put your `ExternalProject` code in a separate file, say "CMakeLists.txt.dependencies" and then launch another cmake with `execute_process`.  I use `configure_file` first to inject configuration information into the external project and to copy it into the build tree.

```
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.dependency.in dependency/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependency" )
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependency" )
```

Notice that the tutorial has the `ExternalProject` code in a separate `CMakeLists.txt` file.  So does `gtest` official documentation.  That is because `ExternalProject` runs at build-time, not configure time.  This is a hack to use `ExternalProject` at configure time by putting it in a third project and executing a separate CMake+build run in the middle of your main CMake configuration step.

With version 3.11 CMake added a [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) command.  I haven't used it, but the documentation makes it look like a configuration-time replacement for `ExternalProject`.  That would fetch the content at configuration time, making it available for a later `add_subdirectory` command.

The `ExternalProject` and `FetchContent` commands will work fine for a small number of small and/or obscure dependencies.  If your dependencies are more than 2, large, and/or popular, I recommend you look at a dependency manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/).  It partners with CMake quite well.

Answer (score -2):

You are not following the method correctly. There should only be `ExternalProject_Add()` as the final command in the `CMakeLists.txt.in` file.

The `CMakeLists.txt.in` file is called by the outer `CMakeLists.txt` file so that the subproject processing happens at configure time via `execute_process()`. `CMakeLists.txt.in` is acting as just a glorified downloader.

So, all other commands like `add_subdirectory()` are added to the outer `CMakeLists.txt` file.