# CMake: Build and install locally stored submodule

Tags: c++, cmake, external-project

There are numerous similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none come near to answering my question.

I have a C++ library built using CMake:

```
mylib
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - src/
|   | - m.h
|   | - m.cpp
| - include/
|   | - mylib/
|   |   | - a.h
|   |   | - something/
|   |   |   | - some.h
| - cmake/
|   - mylibConfig.cmake.in
|   - mylibConfigVersion.cmake.in
```

I then create another library or executable which includes the aforementioned library:

```
myapp
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - src/
|   | - main.cpp
| - include/
|   | - myapp/
|   |   | - b.h
| - libs
|   | - mylib
```

And would like to use `mylib` within `myapp` like so. Please take notice how `mylib` headers are included in a directory like format:

```
#include <mylib/a.h>
#include <mylib/something/some.h>
```

`mylib` should be built when building `myapp` so that the following works *without any other build steps*:

```sh
$ cd myapp/build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

Here is a list of some of the Stack Overflow posts I have reviewed. I have attempted each, and they simply do not work:

- [CMake: How to build external projects and include their targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets)
- [CMake ExternalProject_Add() and FindPackage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446981/cmake-externalproject-add-and-findpackage?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It seems that those other questions are about *external* projects while your project has internal library (that is it is inside of directory tree of app project) so I guess `add_subdirectory` should be sufficient. I personally would object such a project organization though.

Comment: I'm a big fan of `cmake --build .` rather than `make`, it's more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming in the project described, only header files in the `mylib/include` directory are to be considered public:

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for `mylib` needs to contain:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)
project(mylib VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(${MyLibName} ${MyLib_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${MyLibName}
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
```

This ensures that projects including `mylib` will only have access to files in the `include/` directory. Files in `include/` can be used like `#include <myfile.h>` and files in `include/mylib` (the general convention) can be used like `#include <mylib/myfile.h>`.

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for `myapp` should include:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)
project(myapp VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(libs/mylib)

add_executable(${MyAppName} ${MyApp_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${MyAppName} ${MyLibName}
```

The use of `add_subdirectory` ensures that `mylib` will be built before `myapp` and `target_link_libraries` adds `mylib` to the executable.

As mentioned by Tzalumen, make sure you take a look at the [CMake tutorials](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) and prefer the use of `cmake --build .` instead of `make`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually do this in one of my projects.

First, the library needs to be built with ADD_LIBRARY(), but I'm assuming you do that. Something like

`ADD_LIBRARY (${MyLibName} ${SOURCES})` in the library's CMakeLists.txt

That adds the library into cmake's list of libraries.

Second, you add the library to your project with

`target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${MyLibName})` in the executable's CMakeLists.txt, the same one where you have your `add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})`

That will set up the dependency chain to force MyLibName to explicitly build before PROJECT_NAME.

Comment: I want the entire process to be done at once. I do not want to CMake and build the `mylib` separately from `myapp`. The project is required to be 110% self-contained.

Comment: When I say it does it first, I refer to the compilation order of a single build. My project builds off one config call and one build call.

Comment: I have a script that does this. Specifically, it makes a `_build` directory, `cd`s into it, calls `cmake ..`, then calls `cmake --build .`, I just sit back and wait for the compilation to finish.

Comment: @paddycakes I'm sorry if I haven't been completely clear, this answer is the standard, correct way to build a library and add it to your project, I learned it directly from the cmake documentation.

Comment: I have worked through the tutorials, but I was looking for further elaboration on each line's purpose. I figured out my issue was not properly adding the include directories to `mylib` with `target_include_directories`.I've added an all encompassing answer.