# Building third party library as part of CMake project

Tags: cmake

I have a top level CMakeLists.txt file which builds a library called Camellia and several executables in subdirectories which link with Camellia. I would like to add a third party library called XDMF as a dependency for Camellia under Camellia/TPL/Xdmf. Luckily, XDMF is already on a CMake build system, but when I use

```
add_subdirectory(TPL/Xdmf)
```

and then

```
add_library(Camellia ${LIB_SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

it builds Camellia in the build/TPL/Xdmf/bin directory rather than build as it does without the add_subdirectory(TPL/Xdmf). Why does adding a subdirectory change the build directory for Camellia, and how do I fix it? Also how do I make sure Camellia is linking with Xdmf once I get that figured out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How to build external projects and include their targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ExternalProject_Add(...)` is what you want.

Please see [CMake: How to build external projects and include their targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets) which describes a similar issue.