# add_subdirectory() without installing anything

Tags: cmake, googletest, cpack

With CMake I use `add_subdirectory(gtest)` to build [gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest) for testing my project. I also use CPack to make an installer.

The problem is the gtest repo (which is a git submodule) runs `install()` on some files so they end up in my installer! Obviously I don't want that. Is there a way to disable `install()` commands for a given subdirectory without just removing them from the CMakeLists?

Comment: Never having used gtest, so this might be a stupid question, but... why are you building a tool not directly related to your project *in* your project? Why don't you build / install gtest seperately and be done with it? (I wouldn't build Boost.Test inside my project either.)

Comment: It simplifies building the project & linking with cmake. If you build it in your tree using `add_directory` then you can just do `target_link_libraries(mytest gtest)` without having to faff around finding it. It's not super elegant but apart from this issue it works really well.

Comment: But the point is, you are using `add_subdirectory()` for something `find_package()` is intended for, found an issue, and now want `add_subdirectory()` to *not* do something it *is* intended for... I wanted to hint that "faffing around" with `find_package()` (which isn't that hard to do) and dropping the `add_subdirectory()` *would* solve your problem. ;-)

Comment: Yes but it would introduce other problems. I have found a reasonable workaround for this issue anyway - explicitly set `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` which excludes the `Unspecified` component.

Comment: Ah that is a better solution.

Comment: Why not build gtest once and use this within your different projects?

Comment: Well... I only have one project. But mainly because it simplifies setup if it is automatically downloaded, and also because this way imports the `gtest` target so you can just do `target_link_libraries(gtest)`. There's an `ExternalProject_Add` function that's meant to help but [it has issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15175318/265521). I think this is just one of the hacky areas of CMake (which is basically all of it but y'know...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to prevent Google Test from being installed:

```
add_directory(gtest EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

Comment: Correct. I [already discovered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43043052/265521) but for some reason didn't answer my own question... :-S