# How can I make a FindMyPackage.cmake module fall back to downloading?

Tags: github, cmake, dependencies, building, buildconfiguration

I have a simple CMake find module I've written, for a [library of mine](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) used by other projects. It's pretty simplistic, with its full text available [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindCUDAAPIWrappers.cmake). Mainly there's one `find_path()` and one `find_library()`, and then some variables are set.

Now, I want CMake, when trying to find my package, to fall back on:

1. git-cloning or downloading the package/library from its GitHub repository,
2. Unpacking the archive, if it was a download
3. Building the package, either be using the running CMake itself somehow (the package has its own `CMakeLists.txt`), or by running an arbitrary shell command in the directory into which the packages was downloaded/cloned

The specifics of what happens post-download are less important to me than actually having a download fall-back.

How can I / how should I make this happen?

Notes:

- Of course if the download/git clone fails, than finding the package has failed.
- No need to worry about specific versions at the repo, although you can if you want to.

Comment: I've seen those Git integrations a lot using `ExternalProject_Add()` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets). Can you please give some details why that wouldn't fit your needs? Or wouldn't just printing a hint on failure how to e.g. to integrate your library as a Git submodule sufficient?

Comment: @Florian: Ah, well, the library doesn't typically install anywhere; although - maybe that could be adapted to work for me anyway.