# Using targets of ExternalProject in CurrentProject

Tags: c++, cmake

Lets say I have two CMake projects - an ExternalProject E and my current project P. E provides two ways to interface with it - It creates a `pkg-config` file and `.cmake` file. I wish to use either of these two options to for using E in P.

**In P's build, I need to achieve the following steps:**

1. Build E
2. Install E. This step would create pkg-config files (`E.pc`) or CMake exported targets file (`ETargets.cmake`)
3. Use `E.pc` or `ETargets.cmake` in P for including E's headers and linking against E's libraries.

I couldn't get my build to work with following options:

1. `include(ETargets.cmake)` in P's CMakeLists.txt. This doesn't work since `ETargets.cmake` is not present at configure time.
2. I didn't find a way to extract information in E.pc from CMakeLists.txt in [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html).
3. `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` route detailed [here](https://samthursfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/cmake-dependencies-between-targets-and-files-and-custom-commands/) for dealing with generated files. This might/might not work, but either way it will introduce lot of boiler plate in my build.

Only solutions I can find are

1. Install E manually and then use `.cmake` or `.pc` files in P (detailed in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets)).
2. Manually scavenging through directory installed by E to find required libraries. (detailed [here](https://mirkokiefer.com/cmake-by-example-f95eb47d45b1)).

Both the solutions outsource some work to outside of CMake build hence are not satisfactory.

Comment: I am assuming you have you thought about using `ExternalProject_Add`? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: ExternalProject_Add(E) builds project E at build time. Therefore, .cmake and .pc files cannot be used to configure P (Point 1 in options I tried).

Comment: So you need to build and install E project at *configure* time of the A project. For that, you may use plain `execute_process`. Alternatively you may use project E via `add_subdirectory` in the project A.