# How to link 3rd party library (ceres-solver) in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, ceres-solver

There's a simple project comprised of only *main.cpp* which uses *ceres* library (3rd party lib).

main.cpp:

```
#include <ceres/ceres.h>
int main() {
    ceres::some_function();
    return 0;
}
```

Previously, this is how I used to code as a very beginner:

1. download *ceres*-related source files -> build with cmake -> compile & install using Visual Studio -> generates *ceres.lib* which I will be using.
2. open up visual studio -> make an empty new project
3. link *ceres*-related .lib and .h files in the project setting
4. create *main.cpp* file and start coding:

   #include <ceres/ceres.h>
   ...
5. build & run inside Visual Studio

Now, I need to make this project (main.cpp) be built with CMake.

**Do I need to configure CMakeList.txt for *main.cpp* such that
ceres.lib is also built *during* the build of *main.cpp*?**

Additionally, can you point me to a CMake tutorial that covers this kind of situation - configuring a project that uses a third-party library which needs to be built as well.

Comment: Have you performed any **research** of your problem? For build 3d-party project during building your own could be performed with `ExternalProject_Add` command. You could find some examples of its usage in that question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the link! I think this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

After installing ceres, you need only to find it and link it via cmake:

```
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(something PUBLIC
    ${CERES_LIBRARIES}
    )

target_include_directories(something PUBLIC
    ${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
```

You can choose to change `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE` or `INTERFACE`.

If ceres was installed correctly, that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(something PUBLIC
    Ceres::ceres
    )
```

Reference: https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/fd6197ce0ef5794bba455fe6f907dcdabcf624eb/docs/source/installation.rst#using-ceres-with-cmake