# Cmake - can I use ExternalProject_Add for an external project that uses Makefile but no Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my CmakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Network LinguistTools)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Network LinguistTools)
include(ExternalProject)
add_subdirectory (dep/socketio)
ExternalProject_Add(HDiffPatch
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/hdiffpatch
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        ${USE_PROJECT_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
        INSTALL_COMMAND "make LZMA=0 ZSTD=0 MD5=0")

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

set(TS_FILES TestProject_en_US.ts)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        TestProject.cpp
        TestProject.h
        TestProject.ui
        components/popupmenu.h
        components/popupmenu.cpp
        ${TS_FILES}
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(TestProject
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        login.h login.cpp login.ui
        resources.qrc
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET TestProject APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation

    qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(TestProject SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(TestProject
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()

    qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
endif()

target_link_libraries(TestProject PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network sioclient_tls)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.TestProject)
endif()
set_target_properties(TestProject PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)


include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS TestProject
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(TestProject)
endif()
```

As you can see this is a C++ Cmake Qt Project.

I want to add external project to my project. That external project is this [one](https://github.com/sisong/HDiffPatch).
As you can see the external project uses Makefile to build itself but not cmake. In their Readme it says to build the project run `make LZMA=0 ZSTD=0 MD5=0` to build it.

If I build it manually there is no issues.

To add this project as external project to my project I have added these lines:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(HDiffPatch
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/hdiffpatch
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        ${USE_PROJECT_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
        INSTALL_COMMAND "make LZMA=0 ZSTD=0 MD5=0")
```

When I try from Clion to build the target HDiffPatch I get this error:

```
cmake-build-debug --target HDiffPatch -- -j 10
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'HDiffPatch'
[ 25%] No download step for 'HDiffPatch'
[ 37%] No update step for 'HDiffPatch'
[ 50%] No patch step for 'HDiffPatch'
[ 62%] Performing configure step for 'HDiffPatch'
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/venelin/Development/BeastBurst-Launcher/dep/hdiffpatch" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make[3]: *** [HDiffPatch-prefix/src/HDiffPatch-stamp/HDiffPatch-configure] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HDiffPatch.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HDiffPatch.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [HDiffPatch] Error 2
```

How can I fix this issue and how can I link `HDiffPatch` so that I can use it as library in my project and execute it's functionalities from my project codebase ?

Comment: Note, that if a directory specified with `SOURCE_DIR` argument already exists, download and update steps are disabled automatically. No needs to explicitly set DOWNLOAD_COMMAND and UPDATE_COMMAND variables in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Standard steps of ExternalProject are represented by CONFIGURE_COMMAND, BUILD_COMMAND, INSTALL_COMMAND options. By default, each such step calls `cmake` with appropriate arguments. For build a non-CMake project, you need to redefine these options to required command lines. E.g.

```
ExternalProject_Add(HDiffPatch
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/hdiffpatch
        # Tell CMake that project doesn't require a separate build directory:
        # all COMMANDs below will be run from the source directory itself
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE TRUE
        # Disable configuration: in most cases it is about calling
        # 'configure' script or similar, which is not needed in your case.
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        # All actions are performed in the build step
        BUILD_COMMAND "make LZMA=0 ZSTD=0 MD5=0"
        # Disable installation step too.
        INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```

As for using artifacts of External Project in your main project, such usage doesn't depends on the type of External Project (CMake or non-CMake) and explained e.g. in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176075/3440745).

```cmake
# Extract source directory which has been used for the External Project.
ExternalProject_Get_Property(HDiffPatch SOURCE_DIR)

# Needed include directories are somewhere inside the source directory
target_include_directories(TestProject PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/include)

# Needed libraries are produced somewhere inside the source directory too
target_link_libraries(TestProject PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/lib1)

# Allow TestProject to be built only after all steps in the External project are completed.
add_dependencies(TestProject HDiffPatch)
```