# How can i link the UnQLite library to my project

Tags: cmake, unqlite

My project structure is as follows:

```
include (directory for header files)
src (directory for source files)
CMakeLists.txt
Build
```

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Gateway)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

 

# List all your source files
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/datamap.cpp
    src/datapoint.cpp
    src/logger.cpp
    src/meter.cpp
    src/Puller.cpp
    src/pusher.cpp
    src/resetDatapoint.cpp
    src/trace.cpp
)

 

# Create the executable target and specify the source files
add_executable(Gateway ${SOURCES})

 

# Include directories for header files
target_include_directories(Gateway PRIVATE include)

find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Gateway PahoMqttCpp)

 

find_package(croncpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Gateway croncpp)
```

I want to add the UnQLite library to my project. I cloned the repo from github and then I created a build directory and I built it. But when I added to my CMakelist these lines to link the library to my project I get an error.

```
find_library(UNQLITE_LIBRARY NAMES unqlite)
if (UNQLITE_LIBRARY)
    target_link_libraries(Gateway ${UNQLITE_LIBRARY})
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "UNQLITE_LIBRARY not found")
endif ()
```

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (message):
  UNQLITE_LIBRARY not found


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: IIRC the source for the library is available as an "amalgamation", i.e. a single source file. You could just build it together with your project as any other source file.

Answer (score 1):

The UnQLite library also uses the CMake build system, so you can just add the unqlite library as a subdirectory of your project (say, a Git submodule for `external/unqlite`)
and do the following:

```
add_subdirectory(external/unqlite)
target_link_libraries(Gateway PUBLIC unqlite)
```

You can even go a step further and use the `ExternalProject` functionality of CMake to pull the sources directly from GitHub as part of your own build process. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets) for an example.