# I am failing at adding a meson project to a cmake project as a dependent library

Tags: cmake, meson-build

I need to add a meson project (specifically jose) to my project where I am using cmake.

This post: [CMake: How to build external projects and include their targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets) is trying to acheive a similar goal but now that time has pass the recommendation is to use FetchContent. However, that does seem to only apply to other cmake projects, not "foreign" projects. At least, I failed to see how to run meson in the examples.

So. I am trying to use ExternalProject_Add, which works perfectly (configure and eventually build jose). But conceptually there is an issue since I also need to add the jose library to target_link_libraries. However, the library is not yet built when cmake configures the whole project.

I think I understand that I need to have jose built during the global cmake configuration.

I try to use execute_process and ExternalProject_Add_Step but failed at making them to work properly. Here are the details

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  jose
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ""

  SOURCE_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jose

  # Configure
  CONFIGURE_HANDLED_BY_BUILD true
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND meson setup ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jose --prefix=${INSTALL_DIR} --pkg-config-path ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib/pkgconfig

  BUILD_COMMAND ninja

  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  TEST_COMMAND ""

)

set(jose_BINARY_DIR "${BINARY_DIR}")
ExternalProject_Add_Step(jose build
    COMMENT "Building jose project..."
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${jose_BINARY_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE jose_build_result
    OUTPUT_QUIET
    DEPENDEES download update
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${jose_BINARY_DIR}
)

add_dependencies(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} jose)
```

There are 2 problems:

- target_link_libraries is still trying to look for josé before it is being built
- if I remove josé from target_link_libraries (for testing) the ExternalProject_Add_Step fails with a message indicating that add_custom_command is trying to add a duplicate custom rule (in jose-build.rule).

My questions

- Am I on the right track with ExternalProject_Add_Step
- If so, how to make it executed before  target_link_libraries is evaluated

Comment: It seems you forgot to adjust **dependencies** between your executable and the external project. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176075/3440745) about how to  do that properly.

Comment: "the ExternalProject_Add_Step fails with a message indicating that add_custom_command is trying to add a duplicate custom rule" - You are adding the step named "build", but that step is autogenerated by `ExternalProject_Add` (and you have even added the command for that step via BUILD_COMMAND).

Comment: The add_dependencies(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} jose) was present in my cmake file. Just not include in my post above.

Comment: As for the build being in conflict with ExternalProject_Add_Step, I did try with no BUILD_COMMAND, BUILD_COMMAND "" in ExternalProject_Add with the same result.

Comment: "The add_dependencies(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} jose) was present in my cmake file." - So, linking via `target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /path/to/jose/library)` should work. Assuming you have specified the correct path for the library.