# What is a good structure for module Integration through Cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to integrate a few different projects that we've been making through CMake. In general, the projects are not uniformly laid out, but have some similarities. For each library, the library typically has test code/executable that I want to maintain...and they also can have their own inter-dependencies. In addition these libraries have been being maintained in separate repositories (mercurial if it makes a difference). The interdependence of the files are like this:

- Library A is independent
- Library B is independent
- Library C is independent
- Library E depends on A,B,C
- Executable 1 Depends on C
- Executable 2 Depends on E
- Executable 3 Depends on E

So each library is generally laid out like this

```
+ LibraryA\
| + CMakeLists.txt
| + LibraryA
| | + CMakeLists.txt
| | + Include\
| | | header.h
| | + Source\
| | | lib.cpp
| + Test\
| | + CMakeLists.txt
| | main.cpp
```

And than the overarching structure is

```
+ Root\
| + CMakeLists.txt
| + LibraryA\
| + LibraryB\
| + LibraryC\
| + LibraryE\
| + Executable1\
| + Executable2\
| + Executable3\
```

With each folder being its own subdirs project. Does this structure make sense with cmake? How do you maintain the dependencies between these projects? (If I change A, Executable 3 should rebuild)?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398937/cmake-and-finding-other-projects-and-their-dependencies/16404000#16404000).

Comment: @Haroogan So the inclusion of the parent projects in the "project" declaration of the CMakeLists makes the dependencies? 'project(B A CXX)' means A depends on B (that's not in the doc)? Is there any way to do this if we don't want B to be aware of A?

Comment: Nope, you got confused by short names of libraries, i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`. The last 2 parameters for `project` are languages `C` and `CXX` that would be used for this project, so `project(B A CXX)` is illegal. `project` has nothing to do with dependencies, it simply sets up the name for the project (1st parameter) and languages (last 2 parameters). I recommend that you first make yourself familiar with CMake and read documentation before pursuing such a challenging task as devising the structure for a huge multi-component project.

Comment: @Haroogan Ah, there is my confusion, which is why I said "Not in the doc". I have used cmake in the past. So just being clear, the thing that set the dependencies is that CMake is smart enough to know that the link_library call B points to the same name as a configured project, and thus is part of the build and not an external library? I'm still not super comfortable with not knowing exactly what happens "under the hood".

Comment: The key point is here, for example: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} B C)`. CMake knows that there are targets `B` and `C` (created by subprojects `B` and `C` respectively) and that they are either static or shared libraries, and therefore you don't have to specify any paths here to link them properly, just link them by their target names.

Comment: @Haroogan nifty. Now if I want to make it so that the end user can override that and build the library pointing to a manual location (so that the cmake call from the subdir could build) I can have them set A_SOURCE_DIR and A_BINARY_DIR. Looks like the safest way is to use find_library on the manually set A_SOURCE_DIR...but I think that's going to override the dependency linking here. Just double checking, the knowledge that B is a target is not available to me?

Comment: Then, you could parameterize `add_subdirectory`, i.e. instead of `add_subdirectory(components/B)` add `add_subdirectory(${B_PROJECT_DIR})`, and ask the user to supply that during the invocation of CMake, for instance: `cmake ... -DB_PROJECT_DIR="D:\Projects\B"`. This is in the case if you still want `B` to be built with your main project all the time. However, usually this is not the case, i.e. if some library is so mature that it really wants to become and independent project, then it's better to use CMake `find_package` concept.

Comment: This would require writing something like `FindB.cmake` module which is well described **[here](http://vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)**. In this case, user would build and install `B` once as all other libraries you know (like Boost, Qt, etc.) and your main project would employ `FindB.cmake` to get proper `${B_DEFINITIONS}`, `${B_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, and `${B_LIBRARIES}`, referring to that installation of `B`. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: @Haroogan Found another way, kindof an intermediate step. 'if (TARGET A)' will check if it is a target. not sure how "good" of a practice it is, so I'm going to focus more on the upper level build using the dependency structure you described. But I think i'm on the right track now, so if you plop a summary of the stuff down below I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, I feel like writing some sort of guide about this because newcomers/intermediaries ask questions like that very often, so I'll post the summarized answer a bit later, and add some more useful tricks too, just a bit later today. I'm sort of busy right now. In the meantime you could upvote my previous answer, if it was helpful. Thanks. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense what you're trying to do.  And you can do it with CMake, even though it may not be immediately obvious how to do it well.  I went through the same thing a while ago, and wrote a question about it here, followed by an answer outlining my eventual solution:

[CMake: how best to build multiple (optional) subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459686/cmake-how-best-to-build-multiple-optional-subprojects/12421394)