# Ninja equivalent of Make's "build from this directory down" feature (with CMake)?

Tags: cmake, ninja

When building a project using CMake and Make, you can execute `make` from a subdirectory of your build tree (i.e. from a directory below whatever directory contains your top-level `Makefile`), and `make` will (as far as I can tell) build all targets at or below that directory. This is because CMake generates a `Makefile` for every directory that contains targets, so when you're in a directory with targets, `make` finds the `Makefile` for building those targets.

When CMake generates Ninja files, however, it only generates *one* `build.ninja` file, which is at the top level of the build tree. So calling `ninja` from a directory other than the top-level directory fails (even the `-f` option doesn't work because `ninja` can't find the `rules.ninja` file).

Is there any way to emulate the "make-like" behavior of building targets at and below a directory? As far as I can tell, there are no Ninja targets that correspond to "all targets at and below a particular directory." (This could be emulated using phony targets named after each directory that depend on all targets at and below that directory, but CMake does not generate such targets by default.)

Answer (score 9):

`ninja <DIR>/all` works with recent versions of Ninja (1.7.2). Version 1.3.4 does not allow this.

I could not find a reference to this on [the manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html). However, CMake has this documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/generator/Ninja.html):

> Recent versions of the ninja program can build the project through the “all” target. An “install” target is also provided.
>
> For each subdirectory sub/dir of the project, additional targets are generated:
>
> - sub/dir/all
>   Depends on all targets required by the subdirectory.
> - sub/dir/install
>   Runs the install step in the subdirectory, if any.
> - sub/dir/test
>   Runs the test step in the subdirectory, if any.
> - sub/dir/package
>   Runs the package step in the subdirectory, if any.

Comment: Awesome! I will try this on Monday.

Comment: ....Ah. This seems to be a CMake feature, not a Ninja feature. (I'm not sure why version 1.3.4 wouldn't support it.) Recent versions of CMake generate those targets with the appropriate dependencies; Ninja itself has no knowledge of their semantics. Unfortunately, my version of CMake (3.2.2) appears not to be recent enough.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
cd <build-root>
DIRECTORY=<path-relative-to-build-root>
ninja -t targets all | egrep "^${DIRECTORY}/" | egrep CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER | \
    sed -e 's/:.*//g' | xargs ninja
```

ninja -t targets all - lists all targets (including target type)

egrep "^${DIRECTORY}/" - filters list of targets to only include those in desired directory

egrep CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER - limits the targets to just C++ executables.  You can remove or tweak this to get the set of targets you're interested in.

sed -e 's/:.*//g' - removes the target type e.g. ": CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER"

xargs ninja - invokes ninja to build the targets

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I would like to know the answer if you find it.
I am just in the process of transitioning to cmake+ninja myself.

I found that I could not create targets with the same name at different levels 
(if there is a way I would be interested to know).
So I adopted a naming convention for different targets
E.g.

`name         - builds program or library
test.name    - runs tests for the named program or library
doxygen.name - build doxygen for the named program or library`

For deeper hierarchies you can do something like:

`doxygen.subproject
doxygen.subproject.name`

Using this pattern you can control precisely what is built but you have to issue the command from the top-level build directory.
I think after I get used to this I will find it more productive as there is no need to change directory before you build or run something and though there is sometimes a little extra typing required the shell history generally has it covered.

This is implemented under the hood by using *add_custom_target()* and adding appropriate dependencies. I use a *macro* to do this automatically so that 
a macro "*add_doxygen()*" will add the doxygen target for the program and make the doxygen target at each higher level depend on it using *add_dependencies()*.

Comment: Targets in Ninja are not hierarchical, which is why they must be uniquely named. We use a custom build script to ensure that CMake and Ninja are always run from the same directory, and we also always use a build directory that is separate from our source dir. This makes full clean builds robust and easy, and allows us to build for multiple platforms.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered the OP question there.

I'm transitioning via makefile generation first myself where that doesn't apply. It was useful to keep to the original structure (retaining in source builds) as in intermediate step. There it would be nice to add targets with the same name applying at each level. 
I'm not entirely sure if cmake itself disallows it. After all you can run make all, make clean and make test on just the subtree you are in.

Comment: I am the OP. Anyway, no, I don't think *CMake* disallows non-unique target names, I'm just explaining why Ninja does.

Answer (score 1):

```
ninja -C /path/to/build_dir
```

On version 1.11.1 this works