# CMake install target dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

I am writing a library that contains library itself and examples and I am using CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
add_executable (example main.cpp)
install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION include PATTERN ".DS_Store" EXCLUDE)
```

When I am running `cmake --build . --target install` - it compiles `example` target and makes installation of `include` directory

I want to exclude building `example` target and make only `include` directory installation when building `install` target and building `example` if running without any special target:

Here I want `example` to be **NOT** built:
`cmake --build . --target install`

Here I want `example` to be **built**:
`cmake --build .`

How should I change my CMakeLists.txt to make it work as I want?

Comment: I think it's impossible. At least the second should be `cmake --build . --target example`. At that point, a possible solution has been investigated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164731/installing-only-one-target-and-its-dependencies-out-of-a-complex-project-with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot exclude *single* CMake target when installing.

The problem is that 'install' target may depends only from 'all' (*default*) target.

While you may remove 'install' -> 'all' dependency (by setting [CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY.html) variable), you **may not add another dependency for 'install'**.

So, before installing

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

either performs

```
cmake --build .
```

or *doesn't build anything* (even library, which you want to build in any case).